# efficient way to scan whole table with celery

Tags: python, django, celery

In our website we want to create hourly reports for our users, our first solution was this (I'm using celery for that):

here is what I use for creating report for a single user:

```py
@app.task
def create_report(user):
    # this method creates report for given user
    pass
```

and then I created this cron task, celery runs this task every 60 minutes:

```py
@app.task
def report_cron():
    for user in User.objects.all():
        create_report.delay(user)
```

this soultion adds the whole table of users into celery queue (we are using rabbitmq).

currently this solution works fine (we don't have lots of user) but can you help with a better solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing particularly wrong with this approach, although it does depend on how long each report takes. For example, if it takes a millisecond per report, then it will spend the vast majority of the total time putting messages on and off the queue and making db connections. About the only tweak I'd make is to allow batching, so you could tune how many reports are generated per task. Then you could try different batch sizes to find the best balance.

Using queues this way is also great as you can scale by adding more workers.

The downside is that the reports won't be precisely hourly, depending on how long messages spend waiting to be processed.

Comment: thanks for response. batching is a good idea I didn't think about that.

creating reports is not a high priority action so I don't insist on creating them exactly after 60m (it can vary)

Comment: as you mentioned putting whole user table in queue may take a little time. when I test our code locally with lots of users (5 million) my system stops responding for a few seconds (when celery is adding users to queue) our current user base is much less than that, but how can I avoid that down time in future?

Comment: Use another celery task to create the other tasks. You want to get your long-running tasks into the background. So you have 1 task that you create on your main thread (creating 1 task is fast), which when it runs creates all the other tasks (this takes a while but it doesn't matter because its running as a celery task and not holding anything else up).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to have to guess some things, because your question doesn't have a lot of information.

Let's say your report is a model, you could create them without saving them and then use [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) to have a single request.

Let's say you need to access foreign key on your User model, you should use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) and [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to optimize your request. Ideally, your task shouldn't do more than one request for all your users plus one per many to many field you need, and one for creating all the reports.

That's all I could advise without more information. Maybe you should add a test at each user iteration to ensure your task does not take more than an hour to do, so you aren't surprise if it happens.

Comment: thanks for response. I think I didn't describe my problem good enough. creating a single report is not my main concern (it can take as much time and db queries as it wants) problem is each time celery runs `report_cron` it will read whole table of users and push it to rabbitmq queue. the process of reading whole table and pushing it to queue can be time/resource consuming. I wanted to know how can I handle this side of problem.